# Creating numeric keys based on unique object names in a database across systems?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, foreign-keys, key

I have a database which uses unique text keys to link between objects.  For example, when users are inserted they are inserted with the text key "{date}-{system}-{user}" where each element of the key is alphanumeric.  This is then checked against a look up table to see if it exists, if not it is inserted into a table and an auto-increment integer key created. Otherwise the same integer key is re-used.

Then, if a unique attribute of that user is inserted, it is matched and assigned the user's numeric key as the foreign key.  For instance, a document unique to this user is inserted with a user key "{date}-{system}-{user}" and a unique text key for the document "{date}-{system}-{user-{document}" from which an integer key is generated.

In this way, there is a numeric key associating these two entries and the document has a unique key for attaching attributes to it.  These are used in various queries.

The problem is the keys, of course, are not the same across systems depending on how and when the elements were inserted.  So, my initial thought was to use a hash as the generated key, but int and bigint are fairly limited, I think.

I'm not sure how SQL server will handle long strings of hashes for foreign keys, I have read it does not do it well in terms of performance.  Otherwise, I could just use the text that is creating the key itself.

How would you go about making sure the int, bigint or string (if plausible) keys are unique across systems, assuming the text key is unique?  A hash?  A GUID?  How could hash collisions be handled if a bigint (63 bits?) bit key were used, if at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Collisions are going to make this a big mess - under most collision avoidance schemes, you search for a new value for the item you're currently trying to assign. Now imagine two texts that hash to the same value, `k1` and `k2`; On one system, it encounters `k1` before `k2` (so `k1` gets the unmodified hash value), and on another system, it encounters `k2` before `k1` (so `k2` would have the unmodified hash value).

Comment: Interesting, I was wondering about a key collision scenario where if the integers matched it just did a text compare on the unique keys associated to the integer, but those queries would get ugly fast I assume, and possibly very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John, you could, if possible, can you rethink your key architecture, because this is the ideal situation to use a GUID for a key. That way you can generate the unique key for any user on any system and be 99.999999999999.......% guaranteed that there will not be any clashes. And this is only 16 bytes too. You can always keep your existing key structure as another column, but only for other purposes perhaps, not to identify or make a record unique. This I would suggest will only be the case if you application uses this information to perform certain tasks, if not, get rid of it completely.

The nice thing about using a GUID as a key in this scenario, is that it is platform independent, ie. you can use it on Oracle, SQL Server, unix, windows ....

Comment: GUID sounds interesting, will a given text key always be the same GUID?  And how will it affect performance going from doing many joins on this integer identifier to using the GUID as the foreign key between tables?  How does it differ from just using the current text key itself, which is programmatically enforced to be unique?

Comment: Your GUID will be a primary key, therefore you will have less overhead joining on this than on a 63Bit key you generate yourself. GUID is only 16bits. Sorting can be slow on very large datasets, because a guid is not sequential, but other than that is is very good, and an industry practice. No an given text key will not 'produce' the same GUID, they are always random and unique. It differs because it WILL be unique and you dont have to come up with algorithms to ensure it, or create it. It is already built in, in just about every language, including SQL

Comment: Sorry, hope my further questions are not annoying, but if the GUID is created uniquely (per system) on every insert, it's not terribly far away from using unique (per system) integers, they would still overlap right?  I think my real problem lies in that there is even an option to 'generate keys' in system A and B when sometimes those keys are copied from A to B.  A GUID would have the same issue in that scenario.  So, if it isn't possible to deal with hash collisions, the problem is just the overall configuration.  (But I really appreciate the education on GUIDs!!)

Comment: @John - I look after a system for one of our customers that consists of 4 different db servers and each inserting about 25K rows per day, in the last 3 years, no collisions. That is the nice thing about using GUID in this scenario. Yes there is a chance to have one key out of 5 billion clash, but I recon you will win the lotto before that happens. I can honestly say that you will not have overlapping keys between systems. Why dont you do a test. Create 2 tables on the same server, and start inserting at the same time say 2 million rows in each table and see if you get any clashes

Comment: I bet you won't get any clashes, and that is just the beauty of it. In SQL Server the way to get a GUID is to call the function NEWID(). There is a whole white paper and thesis on this GUID subject, and at the end of the day there is this tiny chance that you might get one clash, but hey if you do, do a blog on it, and you might become famous, that is how slim the chance is. I have been looking after thousands of Db's over the last 7 years, and done a lot of db development, and have never seen guid clashes. I don't normally use a guid as a PK, but when designing systems like yours, GUID it is!

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot.  I think the problem with this is you get the option "let database B build a an integer key to map to the text key" or "let database A assign the key and copy it to B"  In that case, you could end up with overlapping key values, or if used GUIDs, I'd have two GUIDs mapped to the same key... I'll have to know a bit more about the system before I can determine if that is a problem.  (It shouldn't happen, but it's a legacy thing... what can I do.)  But I really appreciate the answers, they are very detailed and I really appreciate the time you took to answer them!!

Comment: @John - No worries. There could be another option, and that is to create a single mapping table. That says *key1 maps to key-x on server y*. But that will simply be a lookup table, but could work. Or you could then have your mapping table with a INT Primary Key, and have the text key column in there and then a column for every server that it is on, and the key that it is in the DB on the other servers.